# How does the 'class' syntax work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am working on building an api service for a react native app and I am curious what the difference is between a function that sets up instances and then returns an object with closures around the api functions like this:

```
export default AuthApiService = (bearerToken) => {

    const instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: `http://${BASE_URL}`,
            timeout: 5000,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 Authorization: `Bearer ${bearerToken}`
            }
        })

    const signup = async (email, password) => {
        try {
            const response = await instance.post(`/users`, {
                email,
                password
            })
            return response.data
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('error in signup api call', err, err.response)
            throw err
        }
    }

    const facebookLogin = async () => {
        try {
        } catch (err) {}
    }

    return {
        signup,
        facebookLogin
    }
}
```

and a class that creates the object with the constructor syntax and has direct access to the methods of the object like this:

```
export default class AuthApiService {
    constructor(bearerToken) {
        this.instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: `http://${BASE_URL}`,
            timeout: 5000,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 Authorization: `Bearer ${bearerToken}`
            }
        })
    }

    signup = async (email, password) => {
        try {
            const response = await this.instance.post(`/users`, {
                email,
                password
            })
            return response.data
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('error in signup api call', err, err.response)
            throw err
        }
    }

    facebookLogin = async () => {
        try {

        } catch(err) {

        }
    }
}
```

In javascript class syntax basically just a function that creates an object with a different prototype?

Also if you could give opinions about which approach is "better"?

Thanks

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e A great read.

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other programming language, classes essentially just follow the object-oriented approach. There really isn't much of a difference besides the syntax and how it is understood.

In JavaScript particularly, a key difference is the use of the `constructor` function to create an object from a class. This constructor can later be tracked, whereas a regular function this cannot happen. JavaScript technically doesn't even have "classes". The class syntax was added with ES6, and it's pretty much a standard function under the hood.

Regarding which approach is best, it really is up to you. In my opinion, less is more, and simplicity and readability are the most important thing in programming. I would familiarize yourself with both approaches, especially if you plan on working with React because of the pre-hooks era and the current hooks trend.

Comment: "classes essentially just follow the object-oriented approach" from a code readability standpoint yes you are correct, but under the hood, classes in javascript are implemented completely different than "any other programming language" this is due to JavaScripts prototypal chain. Javascript is not a class-based language & classes in JS were wanted by the java kids.

Comment: @DanStarns: There is nothing wrong with making a language more ergonomic by introducing new syntax. `class` syntax is primarily a vehicle for succinctly  expressing something that has existed in JS for a long time.

Comment: @FelixKling yo, I never said anything was wrong with it.

Comment: @DanStarns: *"classes in JS were wanted by the java kids."* gives that impression though.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend staying away from classes if at all possible (In Javascript) checkout this video on [factory functions with fun fun function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImwrezYhw4w)  for why factory functions are usually better. Class.prototype can be tricky, and the "this" keyword in javascript can be tricky without properly binding method calls with .bind(this). React even has you bind the method in the class.

This is not to say classes are incorrect in any way, just that they can be unnecessarily complicated in javascript.

Comment: There's nothing I can agree with here.  Classes are not difficult at all in Javascript, particularly with the `class` syntax.  While there are certainly some situations where something other than a `class` definition is the right way to go, there are zillions of decisions where they make a lot of sense and are easy to program and use.  Likewise, factory functions have their place too, but there's no reason to never use a class and always use a factory function.  For example, I'd like to see how simple inheritance is when only using factory functions.

Comment: So i assume you didn't see the part about classes are not incorrect in any way? I didnt say classes are so complicated that you should never use them, just that javascript makes them unnecessarily complicated. And using Object.create you can have inheritance, so id say pretty simple.

Comment: You should give https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e a read.

Comment: I've read it.  It's an opinion piece and I don't agree with much of it.  Just because it's on the internet doesn't make it correct or an opinion that everyone thinks is right.  I'm entitled to my opinion.  I haven't had any problems using the `class` syntax and I find it simpler, cleaner to inherit with and extend, easier to debug, etc...

Comment: Feels ironically said, but do you. Like I said, nothing wrong with classes, just much more complicated in JS than most other languages (Unnecessarily so) Checkout react hooks as hooks begin to phase out React classes.

Comment: Let me just say that i do in fact love classes in most languages. Class syntax is nice and easy to read. In python i use classes whenever possible. This is a **javascript specific answer**.